# Eclipse Che - How to connect an existing Eclipse installation?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-che

I am very interested in eclipse che and therefore set up a test account on codenvy. I tried several templates, everything works so far.

Under https://eclipse.org/che/features/ it says that you can "connect an existing ide via a ssh sync point"

Does anybody know how to do so? I watched a lot of videos on youtube, searched the documentation, but didn't get any answers.

Do I understand that feature correctly, that you can use the browser ide and your existing ide to connect to your workspace hosted in a docker container? So that people can work in a browser while travelling and in a desktop ide while at home?

Answer (score 1):

Once your workspace is started in Codenvy, click `SSH` button on the Consoles panel. You'll find there all the details necessary to connect your local IDE.

Check docs at https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/desktop-ide-mounting for more info on that.

Comment: Maybe this was once visible, but these days it just says "*Not Yet Active*

The creators of this project are still working on making everything perfect!"